# обязательный аргумент при наличии другого typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-типы

Как я могу описать то, что функция принимает пропсы "title, subTitle, children", а так же если указан необязательный пропс "tabs", мы обязательно должны передать "selectedTab"?

Моя попытка:

```typescript
interface IResourceAsideProps
{
    title: string;
    subTitle?: string;
    children?: ReactNode;
}

interface IResourceAsideWithTabsProps extends IResourceAsideProps
{
    tabs: ITabsItem[];
    selectedTab: string;
}

function AsidePanel({ title, subTitle, tabs, selectedTab, children }: IResourceAsideProps | IResourceAsideWithTabsProps) { }
```

Но я получаю такую ошибку:

> (parameter) tabs: any
> Свойство "tabs" не существует в типе "IResourceAsideProps | IResourceAsideWithTabsProps". ts(2339)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так.

```
interface IResourceAsideProps {
  title: string;
  subTitle?: string;
  children?: ReactNode;
}

type IResourceAsideWithTabsProps =
  | {
      tabs: ITabsItem[];
      selectedTab: string;
    }
  | {
      tabs?: never;
      selectedTab?: never;
    };

type Props = IResourceAsideWithTabsProps & IResourceAsideProps;

function AsidePanel({ title, subTitle, tabs, selectedTab, children }: Props { }
```

Comment: Тип "{ title: string; tabs: ITabsItem[]; }" не может быть назначен для типа "IntrinsicAttributes & (IResourceAsideProps & IResourceAsideWithTabsProps)".
  Свойство "selectedTab" отсутствует в типе "{ title: string; tabs: ITabsItem[]; }" и является обязательным в типе "{ tabs: ITabsItem[]; selectedTab: string; }".ts(2322)

Comment: В идеале оставить только вторую ошибку, что отсутствует свойство.

Comment: Поправлю ответ через часа два-три.

Comment: @OliverPatterson https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-thunder-6glis7?file=/src/Avatar.tsx посмотрите тут. Создал простенький компонент для проверки. Вроде работает так как вы хотели.

Comment: та же самая ошибка, что я и писал в комментариях.